# AWS lambda not working with Log4j 2 appender

Tags: aws-lambda, log4j2, apache-commons-logging

I am trying to write a java based lambda function. Everything works fine except the logging. I have the log4j2.xml file in classpath.

I have also followed the instruction laid down in [AWS Lambda LOgging in Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html) to the word.

I get this in the log when I trigger the Lambda function.

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient).
>   log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
>   log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

I use maven to package the jar. The pom.xml has the following dependencies.

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazon.alexa</groupId>
  <artifactId>alexa-skills-kit</artifactId>
  <version>${alexa.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.commons.io</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
  <version>1.9.40</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure what else I must do to make this work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please note that there is/was a bug in the AWS documentation for lambda logging in java. I have pushed a fix to github for it, but in the mean time see my answer to another post it may be what you need.

tldr; remove `.LambdaAppender` from the `packages` attribute of the `<Configuration ...` tag

see [this other stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973441/logging-using-log4j2-on-aws-lambda-class-not-found/49973486#answer-49973486)

Answer (score 1):

That error message is produced by an old version of Log4j (1.2.x) that’s on the classpath somehow. Log4j 2.x error messages look different.

Please remove the Log4j 1.2.x jar from the classpath. If any of the libraries have a dependency on Log4j 1.2, add the adapter `log4j-1.2-api-2.8.2.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

[Logging reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html)

When creating an Alexa Skill - its dependencies already contain `log4j` components, but laking the Log4j appender. Add [aws-lambda-java-log4j2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-lambda-java-log4j2) to dependencies:

**Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**Gradle:**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.1.0'
}
```

**Error variants**

*No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.*

Add:
`log4j2.xml`  (described in [Logging reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-logging.html)) to `src/main/resources`

*StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console*

Add (same version as in existing dependencies):

```
   dependencies {
    compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.0'
       compile 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.8.2’
   }
```

*No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.*

Add:
`log4j2.xml`  (described above) to `src/main/resources`

*Error processing element Lambda ([Appenders: null]): CLASS_NOT_FOUND
Unable to locate appender "Lambda" for logger config "root"*

Add:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-log4j2:1.1.0'    
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The real issue that is occurring here is lambda requires the use of a shadowJar (shaded jar) which does not work correctly with log4j2 without an additional transformation, this is known albeit somewhat hard to grok issue...

To try to bring all these posts together to enable faster resolution of this issue see below

- [log4j JsonTemplateLayout doesn't work when jar file built by shadowJar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71458136/log4j-jsontemplatelayout-doesnt-work-when-jar-file-built-by-shadowjar)

  - Original post that clued me in
- [Console contains an invalid element or attribute "JsonTemplateLayout" even after adding dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75838785/console-contains-an-invalid-element-or-attribute-jsontemplatelayout-even-after/76681723#76681723)

  - Full example of how to fix in maven or gradle
- [How correctly log AWS Lambda event with lambda powertools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74739764/how-correctly-log-aws-lambda-event-with-lambda-powertools/76681756#76681756)

  - Explanation with powertools
- [Logging using Log4J2 on aws lambda - Class not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49973441/logging-using-log4j2-on-aws-lambda-class-not-found/76681833#76681833)

  - Explanation where someone is claiming the issue is due to a bad path name (that is probably not the case)